# How can I create grid with data from table cron_schedule

Tags: magento2, php

I need to create a grid in the admin panel, which will display data from the cron_schedule table. The data to be displayed will be filtered by the column job_code = test_job. How can I implement this? (Magento 2)

Comment: You can use this ready to use extension from mageplaza which offers some extra features too. https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-cron-schedule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to install extension [EthanYehuda_CronJobManager](https://github.com/Ethan3600/magento2-CronjobManager)

Doesn't make sense to spend extra time to implement already implemented and available logic.

P.S. I've tried a lot cron management extensions and can advice this one as best one