# Override the product alert cron frequency configuration to “Never”

Tags: product, cron, crontab, magento-cron, product-alert

Im new at magento and am stuck trying to modify the "catalog_product_alert"

I need to update it so even if a product has a list of customers subscribed to the stock alert the alert email are NOT sent.
Basically override the product_alert_cron frequency configuration

Is there a way to get the drop down to say never I tried creating a custom module where I added a config.xml file with the code below:

(Drop down defined: vendor/magento/module-product-alert/etc/adminhtml/system.xml)

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <catalog>
            <productalert_cron>
                <frequency>
                Never
                </frequency>
            </productalert_cron>
        </catalog>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: Do you want to don't notify customers for specific product or disable the feature at all. It's not clear with your description. Please provide more details about expected result. Feel free to update question and post additional comment about this.

Comment: @Victor Tihonchuk, I updated the question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun I'll provide few ways how to do this:

**1. Disable extension**

You can disable extension from your system at all, but EE extension `Magento_CatalogStaging` depends from it and you probably can have some issues with EE.

**2. Disable functionality with configuration**

You need to disable `catalog/productalert/allow_price` and `catalog/productalert/allow_stock` in configuration (See Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Product Alerts (check for all stores)) and the system will run `Magento\ProductAlert\Model\Observer::process` but will not run send logic.

**3. Create plugin**

You can create plugin for `around` to `Magento\ProductAlert\Model\Observer::process` and don't run logic at all

**4. Schedule to 30th Feb**

You can change schedule into 30 Feb, but you need to reset `config_path`

```
<schedule>0 0 30 2 *</schedule>
```

**5. Use 3rd party Cron Manager**

Install something like **EthanYehuda_CronJobManager** https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/358615/91782 and manage your processes with.

**Summary:**

I think method 2 is best and easy for you

Comment: thanks for the help I was able to achieve stopping the cron job with your suggestion but Im still having trouble with the drop down, I edited the question above

Comment: For implement something like Never you need to change `source_model` (declare new instead of \Magento\Cron\Model\Config\Source\Frequency) and `backend_model` to add Never option and process it. I don't see sense to do this.